# Is there any way to add TYPE_ID header to kafka consumer when using spring Cloud stream

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Need to add type information to consumer record header before processing message for successfull deserialization. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the header, you can simply tell the deserializer which type you want it to convert the JSON to. There are several ways to do that.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#json-serde